# Jquery each inside of function failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that will loop through a series of divs, single out the divs that contain a `small` element, clone the contents of the `small` element, search through another block on the page to find the `li` element whose index matches that of the current div in the loop, then insert the contents cloned from the small `element` into the `span` element within that div.

I've got it working up until the part where it's supposed to insert the cloned content into the `li`. Nothing happens. Also, the entire thing fails when I attempt to put it in a function as shown in the code that I've commented out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//function NewPosts(){
    jQuery('div.tracked_tags > div').each(function (i) {
        var thisIndex = jQuery(this).index();
        if (jQuery(this).find('small').length){

            var postCount = jQuery(this).find('small').contents().clone();
            //alert('Hey'+postCount.html()+''+thisIndex+'');

            jQuery('div#right_column ul#tracked_tags li:eq('+thisIndex+')').find('.count').contents(postCount).alert(postCount);
            //setTimeout(arguments.callee, 30000);
        }
    });
//};
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HNGJX/1/) The alerts aren't important, I just stuck them in for troubleshooting.

Per suggestion, this is basically the code I'm starting with:

```
<div class="tracked_tags">
        <div>
                <small id="blah" class="count">10 new posts</small>
                                                    </a>
        </div>
        <div>
                <small id="blah2" class="count">5 new posts</small>
                                                    </a>
        </div>                      
</div>

<ul id="tracked_tags">
<li><a href=""><span class="count"></span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span class="count"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is what I want to end up with:

```
<ul id="tracked_tags">
<li><a href=""><span class="count">10 new posts</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span class="count">5 new posts</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**: I'm not sure why, but the portion of the code that copy/pastes the content from one element to the other suddenly started working. I've tweaked a few things so I'm not sure what ended up doing it, but huzzah!

However, the whole thing still fails is I uncomment the function wrapping it. I need it to be in a function so that it can re-run every 30 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed your explanation. Can you build a jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: your jsfiddle looks like a userscript to me

Comment: so WHY didnt you say it?? damn... and you should tag it [tag:userscripts]

Comment: ...Because it's still Jquery and I didn't think it would make any difference. The code's still the same.

Comment: you are wrong. it changes everything. the jsfiddle is useless if the problem is related to a userscript

Comment: I'm really confused about why it being a userscript affects the functioning of the each loop. The element I'm trying to insert content into is one that I created myself earlier in the script. Like I said, everything else is working, I just need to figure out why it's not outputting content I'm cloning into the element I'm trying to send it to. I assume my syntax is wrong somewhere in that line.

Comment: "Userscripts" does not appear to be relevant to this question, even if the code will be used in one.  At first glance, code appears to have a few errors; more later, if I feel frisky.  It might be better if you **post before and after snippets of the target/desired HTML**, so that we can catch all the issues at once.

Comment: @BrockAdams I didn't think the userscript tag was relevant either, personally. Anyway, I added a sample of the desired code result in the main post.

Comment: @BrockAdams tagging accordingly is always relevant. if not, SO could remove "retag" from the site. Plus, since it's a userscript, he could be loading jquery in a wrong way, or could be a `@grant` issue, etc, etc, etc. But we would never know, because he didn't say it, and didn't tag it. With all due respect to your 18k rep, i believe you're wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and not [.contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to inject the data.

Change

```
find('.count').contents(postCount);
```

to

```
find('.count').html(postCount)
```

Comment: I had it as HTML originally, but it wasn't doing anything then either so I switched it to contents to see if that would work instead. I added a fiddle to the original post to show what I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

As for the commented code:

```
//function NewPosts(){
//};
   ^---REMOVE THIS
```

More things:
It seems the .contents() only works as getter, not setter as you imply with `.contents(postCount)` see the [api reference](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

Answer (score 0):

Key issues:

1. `.alert()` is not a property and can't be chained like that.
2. In the Fiddle; that userscript jQuery code is no good (it breaks in Firefox, among several other sins).  Omit such code from the Fiddle as it is not relevant to the question asked and breaks the fiddle for most (maybe all) users.
3. Once wrapped in the function (`NewPosts`), the code will not fire unless called from within `myFunction()` (Or a later, injected `<script>` node).

Lesser issues:

1. If the post count is just text (as seems likely from the sample HTML, do not use `.contents()` or `.html()`.  Just use `.text()`
2. Likewise, onless the content contains HTML nodes, especially with event listeners, there is no need/point for `.clone()`.

Anyway, fixing issues 1, 2, and 3 makes the code seem to work.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNGJX/2/).

```
function NewPosts () {
    jQuery('div.tracked_tags > div').each(function (i) {
        var thisIndex = jQuery(this).index();
        if (jQuery(this).find('small').length){

            var postCount = jQuery(this).find('small').contents().clone();
            //alert('Hey'+postCount.html()+''+thisIndex+'');

            jQuery('div#right_column ul#tracked_tags li:eq('+thisIndex+')').find('.count').contents(postCount);
            //setTimeout(arguments.callee, 30000);
        }
    });
};

NewPosts ();
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now except for one thing-- when the function re-runs at the interval in settimeout, it appears to be running the function dozens of more times at each run. I put in an alert to test that it was running, and while I should only be getting five alerts each time with my full code, I get 12+ at the first 30 second interval, then dozens more at each run after that. Not sure why.

Comment: Nevermind! I moved the timeout function outside of the each loop and it's running correctly now. Last thing I need to do is figure out why the heck my script is affecting other sites that load Jquery when I've got it set to only run on one domain, then I'll be good to go!